# When logging to CloudWatch logs in a JSON format what is the name of the timestamp property and what is the expected format?

Tags: datetime, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm logging to CloudWatch logs using a logging framework that sends JSON. At the moment every log in CloudWatch is being logged with the same date.

What is the name of the JSON property that CloudWatch Logs looks for to determine the date/time of the logged event and what format does it have to be in to be logged correctly.

Are these details documented by AWS and if so, where? Cause I can't find it within the CloudWatch logs documentation...

Here's my example log at the moment:

```
{
    "time": "2022-02-16 19:11:29.9734",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "message": "Something went wrong...",
    "callsite": "My.NameSpace.Services.ImageDetector",
    "logger": "My.NameSpace.Services.ImageDetector",
    "url": "https://example.com",
    "action": "CheckImage",
    "ipaddress": "8.8.8.8.8",
    "user": "root"
}
```

But it's logging with the datetime `2022-02-14T01:12:47.160+00:00` every time.

Or can it only be sent along with the API call and is not pulled out of the log contents itself as I think it is?

Comment: please share your CloudWatch Agent config, especially `timestamp_format` value

Comment: I have found my answer now, it seems that I was looking for "discovered fields" as I wish for it to capture my logs from console output 
from my aws lambda instead of by posting to the cloudwatch API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a concept of "discovered fields" when posting JSON to CloudWatch. One of these is the log timestamp.

If you post a `timestamp` field in your JSON payload it will auto detect the timestamp from the value.

This can be confirmed by querying for log entries in CloudWatch insights. The log entry only included a `"timestamp"` field, but the auto generated `@timestamp` value is filled:

Please note that the timestamp display in CloudWatch displays the timestamp in your local timezone:
[image: timestamp auto detection by cloudwatch]

Discovered fields are [documented here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_AnalyzeLogData-discoverable-fields.html).

Comment: the timestamp field is added automatically, and there are two options to populate it. They either use the message's value or the operation's current time. Please note that in your screenshot, the timestamp value does not match the timestamp filed from the message - '...T17:22:27.77...' and 'T16:22:27.73...'. The difference is negligible. And it happens because of a minimal delay between the time the application writes the message and the logger reads it. Unfortunately, when you parse an existing file, they insert all messages with the same date if the format is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @VictorSmirnov , the difference in the timestamp is UTC vs my local time (Which was BST at the time). The message is always UTC, but it displays it as your local on the AWS cloudwatch dashboard.

Comment: Hi @Luke, the difference is 0.4 of a second — "...27.77..." and "...27.73...". I would not call one hour difference negligible. It strikes when you load many historical events from the existing file. In that case, they come with the same insertion date. Under normal circumstances, there is no noticeable difference.

Comment: As mentioned, the cloudwatch dashboard converts the timestamp that is recorded in UTC (No timezone) to my local timezone for display purposes only. In the UK, it is 1 hour difference between UTC and BST. As for the millisecond difference, to be honest with you I'm not sure why that screenshot shows any millisecond difference, cause when I look at my logs now there is never any difference, but on that one screenshot there seems to have been. There should be no minimal delay shown in the logs, it's either logged at a certain time or it isn't and cloudwatch should parse that time in `@timestamp`

Comment: Please see the updated screenshot that shows an accurate representation. This time without the +1 hour timestamp, because it is no longer UTC+1 hour where I am in the UK now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use the latest [CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html). Please, check the [CloudWatch agent configuration file: Logs section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection).

The agent reads entries from the log file one by one. It then uses the [`timestampFromLogLine()`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/blob/da27bf33f5338200135331c63d518f5e10b42428/plugins/inputs/logfile/fileconfig.go#L167-L200) function to scan the log entry string with RegExp and extract and parse the timestamp.

I think the RegExp for you might be the following.

```
"timestamp_format": "\"time\": \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f\"",
"timezone": "local"
```

Remember to specify the timezone because you do not have it in the timestamp.

Side note: You show log entry as multiline. You might have reformated it for readability when you published it. If it appears like this in the log, you might need the `multi_line_start_pattern` configuration parameter.

For reference, here is my complete configuration file to parse Ghost logs.

```json
{
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "/var/www/victorsmirnov.blog/content/logs/https___victorsmirnov_blog__production.log",
            "log_group_name": "victorsmirnov.blog/ghost-access-logs/{instance_id}",
            "timezone": "UTC",
            "timestamp_format": "\"time\":\"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ\""
          },
          {
            "file_path": "/var/www/victorsmirnov.blog/content/logs/https___victorsmirnov_blog__production.error.log",
            "log_group_name": "victorsmirnov.blog/ghost-error-logs/{instance_id}",
            "timezone": "UTC",
            "timestamp_format": "\"time\": \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f\""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example of the log line

```json
{"name":"Log","hostname":"ip-10-100-12-1","pid":21129,"level":30,"req":{"meta":{"requestId":"157ece9f-ed91-412b-9cf1-695a97d0aebd","userId":null},"url":"/health","method":"GET","originalUrl":"/health","params":{},"headers":{"host":"10.100.12.1:2369","connection":"close","user-agent":"ELB-HealthChecker/2.0","accept-encoding":"gzip, compressed"},"query":{}},"res":{"_headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","cache-control":"public, max-age=31536000","location":"https://10.100.12.1:2369/health/","vary":"Accept, Accept-Encoding","content-type":"text/plain; charset=utf-8","content-length":"66"},"statusCode":301,"responseTime":"1ms"},"msg":"","time":"2022-08-04T00:00:27.348Z","v":0}
```

The `@timestamp` column generated by CloudWatch matches the `time` property parsed from the JSON record.

[image]